# Execute default exception handler after executing custom error handle

Tags: php, exception

In PHP I have built an error handler using `set_exception_handler` function. It is executing my custom exception handler. I want PHP to execute default exception handler too after executing my handler. Here is my code.

```
function handleException( exception $e){ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    restore_exception_handler(); 
} 

set_exception_handler( 'handleException');
```

`echo $e->getMessage()` is executed but then the default PHP exception handler doesn't get executed even after using `restore_exception_handler`. So, How can I make it works?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14976548#14976548

Comment: What do you mean with `default exception handler` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should trigger previous exception handler after restoring it

```
function handleException( exception $e){ 
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
    restore_exception_handler();
    throw $e; //This triggers the previous exception handler
} 

set_exception_handler( 'handleException');
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't thought of using `throw` inside the handler and ended up wasting lot of time

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) is clear about that:

> Sets the default exception handler if an exception is not caught within a try/catch block. Execution will stop after the exception_handler is called.

There is no chance to run any code after that.

But however, you can just call it explicitly:

```
try {
    // some code that throws an Exception
} catch(Exception $e) {
    handleException($e);
    // .. run custom handler now
}
```

No need to use `restore_exception_handler()` here.